# How to create a pivot table with just one section of a column as the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in python, that I want to aggregate within a pivot table.

```
               date      A     
2017-04-01 00:10:00     10
2017-04-01 00:20:00     20
2017-04-01 00:30:00     10
2017-04-01 00:40:00     40
2017-04-01 00:50:00     50
2017-04-01 01:00:00     15
...                     ...
2017-04-30 23:50:00     20
```

I am trying to create a pivot table that aggregates the data in column A for each day. So my index in the pibot table would just be the day of my 'date' column.
I tried to split my 'date' column and than creating a pivot table with my new df, but I'd like to know, if there is an other way to create a pivot table with my current df.

My intended result would look like this

```
      date   A 
2017-04-01  14
2017-04-02  21
2017-04-03  20
...         ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use pd.Grouper i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'),aggfunc='mean')
```

If date is your index then

```
df.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(level='date', freq='D'),aggfunc='mean')
```